# Cat's curve and some properties

Tags: derivatives, soft-question, curves

Well, it's my cat which inspired me today . The goal was :find a curve using elementary function which looks like my cat and I have found this :

> > let $0<x<1$ the cat's curve is defined by the following function :
> > $$f(x)=(1-x)^{\cos^2\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)}+x^{\cos^2\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}\Big)}-1$$

The [graph looks like so](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mlv3jjh3g1):

[image]

As far as I remenber it recall me a little bit the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) in the neightborhood of zero or one .
Furthermore there is a big problem with the derivatives but I don't go further than the first .Maybe it's a little bit fractal .

Do you know some others interesting properties of this curve ?
Exists there others curve of this kind ?

Thanks in advance cheers .:-)

### Update:

As heropup make a good remark I propose to prove that :

$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx<\frac{2}{3}$$

Moreover if we look at the graph of one summand I think it's hard to use taylor series (even unsuable maybe).So I don't know what tools use for.

Comment: The graph of $f$ is funny to look at. But we need an interesting question about it.

Comment: The area under $f$, to within $8$ decimal places, is $0.66624983\ldots$ which is coincidentally "close" to $2/3$.

Comment: Well, it's infinitely differentiable on  $(0,1)$ so it's certainly not fractal. :)

Comment: Repeating jokes, just prove that $\sin \left(\frac{5 \pi }{21}\right) \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{31}\right) < \frac 23$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

so that the areas above and below the parabola may cancel.

Comment: Is it too good to be true ?If you say right that's truly gorgeous and orgasmic !! Ps: Is it the cage of the cat (lol).Thanks for your effort (+1)

Comment: based on herpup`s calculation $ y=4x(1-x)$ parabola